# Store date in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

The given date format in CSV is '(Fri) 09 Jan 2018 (32)'. This should feed to database as a date column to allow order by date. How could convert above format to Neo4j date format at the insertion time ?

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

```
WITH '(Fri) 09 Jan 2018 (32)' as inputString
WITH split(inputString, ' ') as parts
WITH parts[1] + ' ' + parts[2] + ' ' + parts[3] AS concatDate
RETURN apoc.date.parse(concatDate, 's',"dd MMM yyyy") as date;
```

**Explanation:**

- line 1: defines a date for testing purpose
- line 2: splits the given date into its pieces at each blank
- line 3: concatenates the day, month and year
- line 4: parse the built date of line 3 and convert it to a Neo4j date

### Result

```
╒══════════╕
│"date"    │
╞══════════╡
│1515456000│
└──────────┘
```

---

### Alternative solution

```
WITH '(Fri) 09 Jan 2018 (32)' as inputString
WITH split(inputString, ' ') as parts
WITH reduce(s = "", x IN parts[1..4] | s + x) AS concatDate
RETURN apoc.date.parse(concatDate, 's',"ddMMMyyyy") as date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the date substring always starts at offset 6 in the input string, this will return the date offset from `01 Jan 1970`, which is adequate for comparing dates:

```
WITH '(Fri) 09 Jan 2018 (32)' as s
RETURN apoc.date.parse(SUBSTRING(s, 6, 11), 'd', "dd MMM yyyy") as date;
```